# Subspace Lebesgue Measure on $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I am writing a question on subspace Lebesgue measure and answer of the same for a solution verification

**Question** Let $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and let $\mathcal{Q}$ be the Borel Sigma algebra on $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\lambda$ be the restriction of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{Q}$. Find out the measure subspace $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathcal{Q}, \lambda).$

**Answer** Any member of $\mathcal{Q}$ is of the form $\mathbb{Q}\cap U$, where $U$ is a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$. Let $r\in \mathbb{Q}$ be arbitrary. Obviously, $[r,r+\frac{1}{n})$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $n$. Now,

$$\mathbb{Q}\cap \bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty [r,r+\frac{1}{n})=\{r\}.$$

Therefore, $\{r\}\in \mathcal{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, this shows that $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})\subseteq \mathcal{Q}$, where $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$ denotes the power set of $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})= \mathcal{Q}$.

Now, let $\mathscr{M}$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then for any member $A\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q})$,

$$\mathscr{M}|_\mathbb{Q}(A)=\lambda(A).$$

However, since $A$ is at most countable, we have $\mathscr{M}|_\mathbb{Q}=\lambda\equiv 0$. Therefore, the required measure space is $(\mathbb{Q}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Q}), 0).$

I am new in Measure theory, any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Yes, this looks correct.

Comment: Thank you @NateEldredge for your time.